# java how to know if a process is waiting for input

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a process in java that starts a external file that asks for a number of arguments which the user gives at execution time.

The question is how to determine if the precess is asking for a argument

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(c.fileName);
    Process proc = null;
    try {
        proc = pb.start();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(clas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    Scanner in = new Scanner(proc.getInputStream());
    PrintWriter out = null;
    out = new PrintWriter(proc.getOutputStream());
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println(in.nextLine());
        out.println(1); // i don't want to give 1 untill the process need it ! 
        out.flush();
    }

    out.close();
```

Comment: Perhaps you should listen and respond to the process's InputStream, and hopefully it will send something when it wants to accept data (this all depends on the process of course).

Comment: Possible duplicate ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826070/java-runtime-process-check-if-waiting-for-input